# PHP Anonymous function with array_walk

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I'm trying to use array_walk with an anonymous function, but I always get the error

```
 // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in ... on line X
 if(!empty($myArray)) {
   array_walk($myArray, function(&$value, $key){ // Line X
     $value = '"'.$value.'"'; // Add quotes
   });
 }
```

The surrounding file syntax is correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, true anonymous functions (closures) are only available from PHP 5.3, however you can still create an anonymous function in earlier versions of PHP using the [create_function()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) call, which can be used with array_walk(). Something like:

```
array_walk($myArray, create_function('&$value,$key', '$value = \'"\'.$value.\'"\';'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Check your PHP version... Anonymous functions are only available since 5.3...

Comment: Oh, I had no idea this was a version issue. Thanks!