# array_walk throwing a warning; claims invalid callable

Tags: php, lambda, anonymous-function

Using PHP version 5.4.27, the following code throws a warning and fails.

```
$test = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
array_walk($test, function (&$value, $key) { $value = 1; });
var_dump($test);
```

Result:

> Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in [snip]/test.php on line 3
>
> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Resolved: This is actually due to eAccelerator not working correctly with anonymous functions. Switch to Zend Performance Suite or APC.

Comment: runs fine for me here on 5.5.12

Comment: Some other Stack overflow post spoke of it --> [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066364/array-walk-an-anonymous-function)

Comment: Or [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197853/php-anonymous-function-with-array-walk) with PHP version concern (5.3 <)

Comment: @MartinKonecny Thank you, I'm not sure what's causing this behavior, it should function perfectly well on 5.4+.

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD From what I see, these posts aren't relevant to my situation, thanks though.

Comment: Runs fine on 5.4 here.

Comment: @Carlos Rodrigues First post was about syntax and second about php version. I think this is the only error possibility

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for confirming this might be some environmental issue. I'll need to switch gears to address this apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're running PHP 5.3 or greater? Anonymous functions were only introduced 5.3 and your error message hints this is the case? Here's a snippet that should run on 5.2 and earlier

```
echo phpversion();
$test = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function setOne (&$value, $key) {
  $value = 1;
}

array_walk($test, "setOne");
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: Indeed passing a function name as a string does work but I don't understand why lambdas are causing an issue here. Looking at phpinfo() via browser or php --version via shell is showing the same thing, 5.4.27 :(

Comment: I've added a statement to the beginning to print your PHP version. Please verify it's the version you expect.

Comment: Same, 5.4.27 -- very odd behavior.

Comment: You're right, square bracket notation `[]` for arrays was only introduced in 5.4. Try copying your exact code from your file to here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and see if it runs.

Comment: Works there. In my earlier attempts, I was passing in reference to an object instance outside the scope of the closure, and perhaps there was some issue that is causing PHP to fail as a result. Although, the only error I've encountered while working was this invalid type for the 2nd param. Unfortunately I can't restart the server just yet to see if it's remedied. I'll try to replicate in a different location in the meantime.

Comment: Sounds about right - I was able to recreate your error by passing in an undefined variable. Although if you simply paste this code into a file and run it with `php testfile.php`, there shouldn't be any error state left over from your previous run.

Comment: Reboot didn't help. I'm going to revert to backwards-compatible functionality but I'm stumped because there's no other hints as to what's occurring. I'll dig into some logs tomorrow. Unfortunately recompiling PHP binaries isn't a possibility either.

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you do the following: `$x = function($y) { echo "$y";}; $x("hi");`

Comment: That works, prints "hi," and I can pass $x into array_walk() perfectly well and it'll work in that scenario. But it gets finicky when I try to define & pass the anonymous function in-line.

Comment: Well this is interesting. If I take that seed code from my initial question/post, and I just add a line before it where I assign $x = 1, I get a HTTP 500 error, and Apache writes the follow to error log: `[notice] EACCELERATOR(71253): PHP crashed on opline 9 of array_walk() at [snip]/test.php:4` -- however, disabling eAccelerator doesn't help, just stops that 500 error from occurring.

Comment: Try this http://serverfault.com/questions/340783/how-can-clear-cache-in-eaccelerator